BitLocker как защита от вируса
Я задумался о защите своего компьютера, а главное данных на нем от проникновения разного рода вирусов. Мой вопрос: установив на 11 винду, на основной диск шифрование BitLocker, это защитит его от повторного шифрования каким-нибудь вирусом?

а с какой, собственно, стати вы пришли к столь оригинальной гипотезе?

@aleksandrbarakin гипотеза нуждается в доказательстве. я здесь с целью получить ответ, а не ответный вопрос

Вирусы в большинстве своем работают как обычные программы. Вот вы файл в ексель открыли и там все цифры зашифровали и файл на место записали. При этом BitLocker независимо от вас дополнительно зашифровал то что получено при записи на физический диск, Вот и вирус так же, берет по очереди все файлы и просто переписывает их содержимое и BitLocker не знает сделали лы это вы сами в каком нибудь экселе или это вирус сделал

вот и интересно, какие могут быть (хотя бы чисто теоретические) доказательства у выдвинутой вами гипотезы. пока их не наблюдается от слова совсем: никаким алгоритмам шифрования ведь не должно быть никакого дела до того, что из себя представляют шифруемые байтики - вновь и вновь прозводить шифрование можно до бесконечности.

"...это защитит его от повторного шифрования каким-нибудь вирусом..." - вирусы шифруют? Пользуйтесь антивирусом и помните об элементарных правилах безопасности и о вменяемом поведении. Кроме того, не храните данные на системном диске, резервируйте их - это позволит быстро переустановить ОС.
